# How to upload custom CSV to ChromaDB Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, langchain, chromadb

I'm learning to use ChromaDB. So far I have been able to run some samples from the Chroma guide.
But now, I want to bring in my own CSV file and run the embeddings.
I don't see to connect the dots on how to upload my custom CSV to the ChromaDB image

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  application:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: application
    container_name: application
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    networks:
      - net

  chroma:
    image: ghcr.io/chroma-core/chroma:latest
    volumes:
      - index_data:/chroma/.chroma/index
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - net

volumes:
  index_data:
    driver: local
  backups:
    driver: local

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Can someone guide me on uploading CSV file and running an embedding on it?
My CSV file has ~10K rows and 20 columns in it. (about 90MB)

Comment: What have you done so far?  What code have you written, and what problem are you running into?  I might start with writing a program on the host connecting to the published port 8000, running the database in a container but the program locally, which will make it easier to test and debug.